# UFW is not blocking IPs

Tags: 16.04, ufw, fail2ban

so im working with fail2ban, ufw, and wordpress (NGINX).

I made plugin for creating 401 if someone fail to login

```
function wp_login_failed_403_res() {
  status_header(403);
}
add_action( 'wp_login_failed', 'wp_login_failed_403_res' );
```

Ofc fail2ban is installd UFW is activated.

Inside jail.local i have this

```
[wordpress]

enabled  = true
port     = http,https
filter   = wordpress-login
logpath  = /var/www/site.com/logs/site_nginx.access.log
banaction = ufw-nginx
bantime  = 60
maxretry = 3
```

Inside action.d/ufw-nginx i have this

```
[Definition]
actionstart =
actionstop =
actioncheck =
actionban = ufw insert 1 deny from <ip> to any app "Nginx Full"
actionunban = ufw delete deny from <ip> to any app "Nginx Full"
```

Inside filter.d/wordpress-login i have this:

```
[Definition]
failregex = <HOST>.*POST.*(wp-login\.php|xmlrpc\.php).* 401
ignoreregex =
```

So im trying to block myself :) i'm watching logs and i can see that nginx is registrating 401 on every single failed login.

fail2ban log says this:

```
2017-11-21 20:23:55,906 fail2ban.filter         [10049]: INFO    [wordpress] Found ip.adress.here.xx
2017-11-21 20:24:50,330 fail2ban.actions        [10049]: NOTICE  [wordpress] Unban ip.adress.here.xx
2017-11-21 20:34:10,758 fail2ban.filter         [10049]: INFO    [wordpress] Found ip.adress.here.xx
2017-11-21 20:34:13,642 fail2ban.filter         [10049]: INFO    [wordpress] Found ip.adress.here.xx
2017-11-21 20:34:16,704 fail2ban.filter         [10049]: INFO    [wordpress] Found ip.adress.here.xx
2017-11-21 20:34:17,184 fail2ban.actions        [10049]: NOTICE  [wordpress] Ban ip.adress.here.xx
2017-11-21 20:34:19,240 fail2ban.filter         [10049]: INFO    [wordpress] Found ip.adress.here.xx
2017-11-21 20:34:21,789 fail2ban.filter         [10049]: INFO    [wordpress] Found ip.adress.here.xx
2017-11-21 20:34:25,776 fail2ban.filter         [10049]: INFO    [wordpress] Found ip.adress.here.xx
2017-11-21 20:34:26,508 fail2ban.actions        [10049]: NOTICE  [wordpress] ip.adress.here.xx already banned
```

UFW says this:

```
# ufw status                                                                              
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
Nginx Full                 DENY        ip.adress.here.xx
OpenSSH                    DENY        other.ip.adress.xxx
```

I can still access and login after ban (before fail2ban unban me)

Is there somthing im missing or what?

Comment: I'm no expert but my guess is your problem is with your custom ufw-nginx banaction.  Suggestions: Try substituting one of the banactions that come with fail2ban like iptables-multiport and try it out.

Comment: i switch to default iptables-multiport and same thing nothin happend

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you return 403:

```
function wp_login_failed_403_res() {
  status_header(403);
}
add_action( 'wp_login_failed', 'wp_login_failed_403_res' );
```

And check for 401:

```
[Definition]
failregex = <HOST>.*POST.*(wp-login\.php|xmlrpc\.php).* 401
ignoreregex =
```

In addition you should probably check your log files for the exact log message that is written, and verify that your regex does match that line.